# Stop playing iMacros script if text appears

Tags: imacros

I am currently making a bot using iMacros, I want to stop the iMacros scripts to stop if a certain text appears. 
Currently I have list of 7 scripts (.iim) which need to be played in series. 
I am using `iimPlay()` to do that.

If while playing script 1 text, "Email address already in use", shows up then it should terminate and restart the whole process.

Basically I want that when I am playing scripts in order, while script 1 is playing, if text appears then the whole process should restart. 
I tried:

```js
    setInterval(function() {
      if ( document.body.innerHTML.indexOf("Account already exists") >= 0 ) {
        playMacros();
      }
    }, 5000);
```

but it says `setInterval` doesn't exist. I also tried doing `window.setInterval`, same results. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this issue, you don't need to apply the `setInterval()` function at all. Try the script like so:

```
for (i = 1; ; i++) {
    iimPlay("macro1.iim");

    // check the possible texts
    if (iimPlayCode(
        "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0" + "\n" +
        'SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"Account already exists|Email address already in use"'
    ) == 1)
        continue;

    iimPlay("macro2.iim");
    // etc.
}
```